# How do I click this button using Ruby Capybara?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, capybara

I'm trying to click a button, but I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to find link or button "My Tasks" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

This is what I get when I inspect it on Chrome:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="/tasks" role="button">My Tasks</a>
```

And this is my code (my steps.rb):

```
 # go to my tasks page
    def visitTasksPage
      page.has_content?('Signed in succesfully') do
        clicK_link 'My Tasks'
      end
      self
    end
```

I'm new to Ruby Capybara, can anyone help me please?

Comment: You're using `click_link` when your question is asking about a button.  Try `click_button` instead.

Comment: What driver are you using? Is there CSS changing the case of the "My Tasks" text in your link? Look at `page.html` right before calling click_link and see if the link is actually on the page (and that you're on the page you think you are)

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that it's really a link that you're trying to click (an `<a href="/some-link">Some Text</a>` tag) not a button (a `<button type="button">Some text</button>` tag). To not have this problem, I recommend that you use the following [method](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#clicking-links-and-buttons):

```
click_on('My Tasks') # clicks on either links or buttons
```

Or it could be that the link or button does not appear on the page before Capybara times out. Capybara by default waits 2 seconds before it times out, but you can extend it with

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 9
```

Another thing you can do to debug this problem is add a call to `binding.pry` right before clicking the link/button and check if the button is actually there with the text you expect it to have:

```
page.has_content?('Signed in succesfully') do
  binding.pry # at this point you can test if the link is really there with page.has_content?('My Tasks')
  click_link 'My Tasks'
end
```

Note you would need to [install pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) by adding it to you Gemfile or with `gem install pry`.

Comment: `click_link` is implemented as `find_link(...).click` so that won't make any difference (and as such `click_link` has the same waiting behavior for the matching to link to appear) - and `find_button` doesn't find <a> elements so that's not going to work here

Comment: You're right @ThomasWalpole. Thanks for commenting instead of simply downvoting. I will try to edit my answer with more ways to troubleshoot OP's question.